Is there an option to create custom field on restx, with validate / format
I have create a Resource:
signup_model = api.model('Signup', {
    'email': Email(required=True),
    'password': fields.String(required=True)
})

@api.route('/signup_user')
class SignupUser(Resource):
    @api.expect(signup_model)
    def post(self):
        # logger.info("signup route")
        email = request.json.get('email')
        password = request.json.get("password")
        response = Authenticator.sign_up(email, password, client)
        data = jsonify(response.message)
        data.status_code = response.success
        return data

with a new field called Email (as you can see).
class Email(fields.String):
    """
    Email field
    """

    __schema_type__ = 'string'
    __schema_format__ = 'email'
    __schema_example__ = 'email@domain.com'

    def validate(self, value):
        validate_email(value)
    
    def format(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, str):
           return value
        raise fields.MarshallingError(
           "Invalid type. Allowed types: str"
        )

However, when I send a parameter of email which isn't valid (for an example dakakakaka), it doesnt alert.
I have tried everything
sending on except validate function (which didnt go well)
changing the schema type
tried to inherit from raw instead of string
rewrite code (format function validate function)
Thank you so much
